# ValueError: Cannot use mean strategy with non-numeric data: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-analysis, analysis

sample_real_state = pd.read_csv('Sample_real_estate_data.csv',na_values = missing_val)
sample_real_state
count = 0
for row in sample_real_state["OWN_OCCUPIED"]:
try:
int(row)
sample_real_state.loc[count,'OWN_OCCUPIED'] = np.nan
except ValueError:
pass
count+=1

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp_mean = SimpleImputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean',fill_value="work from home")
imp_mean = imp_mean.fit(sample_real_state)

e data hello I am trying to convert the datatype because

"ValueError: Cannot use mean strategy with non-numeric data:
could not convert string to float: 'PUTNAM'"

this type of error is displaying and even if have try to convert it but not working help me with this issue

Answer (score 1):

Hi  First of all it's really hard to understand your code snippet without formatting. This exception raises because your column contains string-type values. You can't impute using the `mean` because `mean` imputation only works with numeric data.

It looks like the only imputation strategy which `sklearn` supports for string values is `most_frequent`. If this is your desired behavior you can use that:

```py
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy="most_frequent", fill_value=None)
```

Another option would be to fill all those NaN values with a constant value:

```py
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy="constant", fill_value="<your_value>")
```

Also, you can always use `pandas` to fill in missing values on the column level:

```py
data["<string_type_col>"] = data["<string_type_col>"].fillna("<your_value>")

data["<float_type_col>"] = data["<float_type_col>"].fillna(data["<float_type_col>"].mean())
```